# How can you tell if a file is fully downloaded via HTTP?

Tags: http

How can you tell if a file is fully downloaded via `HTTP`?

What if you have flushed the packets from the server, but the user is still downloading them? Won't the `TCP FIN` packet look identical - whether the user has finished or has cancelled the download?

Comment: From which end of the conversation are you interested? The client, or server?

Comment: I'm looking from the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a server to know if the client has received all of the bytes.  All it can do is send and flush the bytes, and then close the connection if an HTTP keep-alive is not being used.  It is the client's responsibility to:

1. detect how the bytes are being sent (normal, compressed, chunked, etc) so it knows how to read them.
2. detect how many bytes are being sent (it will not be able to detect this up front if the data is being sent in a chunked format).
3. detect when all expected bytes have been received so it can stop reading.

So the client, not the server, knows when it has reached the end of the download vs when the download has been aborted prematurely.  If the client known/feels the download is incomplete, it can always re-query the server for the file metadata and compare that to the file is already has, and then re-download if needed.

Comment: Ah, understood. I was trying to figure out if it was possible to figure out if I could log whether the client had truly finished his download.

Comment: The client can log that.  There is nothing in the HTTP protocol to let the server know that the client has finished a download, other than a disconnect, or a new request arriving if an HTTP keep-alive was used on the previous request. But that latter part does not work if HTTP pipelining is used, because then the client could send a new request while it is still downloading the response for a previous request.